# Unmarshal JSON object into slice of structs with key and value

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am still learning GO and I am stumped by the following problem:
I receive a JSON string that I want to unmarshal in GO.
The JSON looks like this

```json
{
  "MAINKEY": {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": [1, 2]
  }
}
```

I am only interested in the contents of the MAINKEY, but similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564216/unmarshal-json-with-arbitrary-key-value-pairs-to-struct) question, I do not know the names of the keys, which should reflect the names of the map.

In the end, I want to have the following object:

```
type Result struct {
    Key   string
    Value []int
}

expectedResult := []Result{
    {"key1", []int{1}},
    {"key2", []int{1, 2}},
}
fmt.Printf("WANT: %+v\n", expectedResult)
//> WANT: [{Key:key1 Value:[1]} {Key:key2 Value:[1 2]}]
```

If possible, I don't want to unmarshal into a `map[string]interface{}` first (but if there is no other way, that would be ok too).

Full code so far is:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// does produce expected result at the moment...
type Result struct {
    Key   string
    Value []int
}

type Outer struct {
    Key Result `json:"MAINKEY"`
}

func main() {

    input := `{"MAINKEY": {"key1": 1, "key2": [1, 2]}}`

    var cont Outer
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &cont)
    fmt.Printf("GOT: %+v\n", cont)

    expectedResult := []Result{
        {"key1", []int{1}},
        {"key2", []int{1, 2}},
    }
    fmt.Printf("WANT: %+v\n", expectedResult)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `var result Result` and then `json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &result)`? Because this does give the desired results.

Comment: I thought I needed the `Outer` to let the unmarshal function find the correct structure of the `Result`. But regardless, the `Result` part is not picking up on the names of the keys.

Comment: Using []Result in the Outer class doesnt fix the values unfortunately

Comment: For a JSON object with unknown keys you have the following options: #1 use a map; #2 iterate over the individual tokens with [`.Token()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.Token); #3 parse the json yourself.

Comment: And in your custom unmarshaler you don't have to use `map[string]interface{}`, you can also use `map[string]json.RawMessage`, which is much easier to subsequently turn into a slice.

Comment: Can you point me to a resource or post a brief proof of concept with the above data? That would be very helpful to me!

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/Epd6cLwyWUm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom unmarshaler with a map:

```golang
type ResultList []Result

func (ls *ResultList) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var obj map[string]json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for key, raw := range obj {
        r := Result{Key: key}
        if raw[0] == '[' { // assume array of ints
            if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, &r.Value); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        } else { // assume single int
            var i int
            if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, &i); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            r.Value = append(r.Value, i)
        }
        *ls = append(*ls, r)
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Epd6cLwyWUm

---

Or, if you need to retain the order, you can tokenize the input:

```golang
type ResultList []Result

func (ls *ResultList) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    d := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(data))
    i := -1
    for {
        t, err := d.Token()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        switch v := t.(type) {
        case string:
            *ls = append(*ls, Result{Key: v})
            i += 1
        case float64:
            (*ls)[i].Value = append((*ls)[i].Value, int(v))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/nABjw5IHZ7R